# Attaching to a process and call `dup2` on aarch64?

Tags: c, process, gdb, arm64, ptrace

I tried attaching to a running process with `gdb` to redirect its *stdout* to an external file with these commands:

```
#Attaching
gdb -p 123456

#Redirecting (within GDB)
(gdb) p dup2(open("/tmp/my_stdout", 1089, 0777), 1)
```

I used the number 1089 because it represents O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND.

Firts, GDB just complained about some missing return types:

> 'open64' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type

So I modified my command to

```
#Redirecting (within GDB)
(gdb) p (int)dup2((int)open("/tmp/my_stdout", 1089, 0777), 1)
```

This was successfully executed, and also works.

I'm trying to figure out how can I write a small utility that does the *exact same* thing as the above:

1. attaches to a process by *PID*
2. calls this `(int)dup2((int)open("/tmp/my_stdout", 1089, 0777), 1)`

Part2 seems easy, however part1 doesn't seem to work on `aarch64`. I could manage to work it on `arm` though.

There are a quite a few solutions which tries to solve this problem:

- [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) (doesn't work on process started by systemctl)
- [reredirect](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect) (doesn't support `aarch64` at all)
- [injcode](https://blog.habets.se/2009/03/Moving-a-process-to-another-terminal.html) (doesn't support 64bit at all)
- [neercs](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/neercs) (for sure no support for `aarch64`)
- [retty](http://pasky.or.cz//dev/retty/) (for sure no support for `aarch64`)

If GDB can work, this is surely possible, but GDB is huge to analyze, and I hope I have some better solution which would not take weeks or months, like digging myself into GDB's source.

Comment: You didn't explain why GDB is not good for you. Can't it be installed? Does it take too much time to start? Please specify your pain and maybe GDB with the proper argument can still be your friend here.

Comment: GDB is too large for my needs, and it's also too heavy (I only need to call `dup2` occasionally, nothing else).

Comment: It is not ideal for your use case but you might be able to use `peekfd` to sniff foreign process fds